# Eyes and rig problems when exporting to .fbx

Tags: armature, export

I have a mesh with 2 eyes parented to the head bone. Their rig is one bone that they track using a Track To constraint. When I export to .fbx and re-import the .fbx to Blender the following problems appear:

1. The eyes unparent from the bone, get teleported in a weird position behind the character and their constraint disappears.
2. The rig adds a "[bone name]_end" to the end of every bone that doesn't have both tips connected to something. Also, some of my bones, like the deform ones disappear.

When I export, I select "mesh" and "armature" and don't bake the animation, because I just need the rigged model for Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, constraints and deform bones don't transfer with .fbx, the way I get around that usually is to instead of constraining an object to a bone, I weight it 100% to that bone.

So I add an armature modifier, select the desired armature from the modifier, and weight the seperate object to the target bone.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to export constraints via FBX or any other format, i am not 100% sure but it's probably the case, and i think it's for all 3D softwares not just Blender

Answer (score 0):

unity does not support blender constraints